# What is the name given to Jesus?

Tags: name-of-jesus, philippians

At his birth he was called JESUS! After his exaltation he was given a NAME! 
Phillipians 2:9

> Wherefore God also hath highly exalted him, and given him a name which is above every name

What is that name?

Comment: Are you referencing some particular piece of scripture for this question, I'm not sure what you're asking exactly in this question.

Comment: @PeterTurner This is a perfectly proper question, not "opinion-based". We know from Acts 4:10-12 that Jesus Christ is the name of the resurrected, and that "there is none other name under heaven given among men, whereby we must be saved". On the other hand, we read in Phil 2:9-11 that "God exalted him and gave him the name that is above every name", but also that "at the name of Jesus every knee will bow", which seems to be a citation of Is 45:23, and therefore to refer to YHWH. It is perfectly legitimate to ask whether the name is Yeshua or Yehovah.

Comment: @MigueldeServet there's not a good close reason for "this is a confusing question".  The question is too open to interpretation, it needed more detail and since that wasn't provided, it was closed.  I'd have closed it as "lacking details" rather than "opinion based" but either one applies.

Comment: @PeterTurner I confirm what I said and explained: the question is perfectly proper, not "opinion-based". The very fact that it elicited as many as 6 Answers, in none of which there was even a hint of a suggestion that the question may be "opinion-based" and/or "lacking details", confirms this. Therefore, AFAIAC, in declaring it "closed", you abused your authority.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complementing Kris's and Nigel's answer, I'd like to add 2 resources; one is [an answer to a similar question](https://www.gotquestions.org/Jesus-name-above-all-names.html) from gotquestions.org.  Another is from an [exegetical commentary on Philippians](https://www.logos.com/product/7861/bible-lessons-international-collection) by [Dr. Bob Utley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Utley).  Commentary on the phrase "and bestowed on Him the name which is above every name" of [Phil 2:9-11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Philippians+2%3A9-11&version=ESV)

> “**and bestowed on Him the name which is above every name**” This special exalted name is “Lord” (cf. v. 11). The verb (*echarisato*) in v. 9 means “graciously given” as in [1:29](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/philippians/1-29.htm). The term “Lord” is an allusion to the OT covenant name for God, YHWH (cf. Exod. [3:14](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=exodus+3%3A14&version=ESV); [6:3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=exodus+6%3A3&version=ESV)), which the Jews were afraid to pronounce lest they break one of the Ten Commandments (cf. [Exod. 20:7](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=exodus+20%3A7&version=ESV); [Deut. 5:11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=deut+5%3A11&version=ESV)). Therefore, they substituted the name *Adon*, which meant Lord, owner, husband. Jesus, who came in the form of a servant, was returned to His cosmic Lordship (cf. [John 17:5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john+17%3A5&version=ESV); [Col. 1:15–20](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=col+1%3A15-20&version=ESV)). “Jesus is Lord” was the public, personal confession of faith for the early Church (cf. [Rom. 10:9](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=rom+10%3A9&version=ESV); [1 Cor. 8:6; 12:3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+cor+8%3A6%2C+12%3A3&version=ESV)). Jesus of Nazareth is given the supreme title of deity (cf. [Eph. 1:21](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=eph+1%3A21&version=ESV) and [Heb. 1:4](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=heb+1%3A4&version=ESV)).

In both of the above resources as well as in Kris's & Nigel's answer, the name is **Lord** (Greek *Adon*), which in the Old Testament as well as the New Testament signifies **the God of Israel** (there are countless texts where the same word is used for God).

This is the highest name (a.k.a title) that a being can have.  God the Father gave this title & honor to Jesus because he was obedient to death, and not only raised him from the dead but also places him at his right hand side (another sign of honor; no other being is honored thus, higher than angels, see [Heb 1](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews+1&version=NLT)).

Within the book of Philippians, the above phrase is part of an early Christian hymn that Paul quoted in his letter to the Philippian church (which he founded) to encourage them (and us) as Christians to emulate (see the larger context of [Phil 2:1-11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Philippians+2%3A1-11&version=NLT)).

Comment: You write, "This [Lord] is the highest name (a.k.a title) that a being can have." Yet, in any language, the difference between a **title** and a (proper) **name** is clear and straightforward, like in "Captain Phillips fought for his boat against the pirates". Now, considering God, _'Adonay_ is a title, whereas _Yehovah_ (יְהֹוָה transl. YHWH) is the **only** proper name of the One and Only God.

Answer (score 3):

It is Peter, the Chief Apostle, who first, publicly, declares that Jesus is 'Lord' and 'Christ'.

> **This Jesus** hath God raised up, whereof we all are witnesses.Therefore being by the right hand of God exalted, and having received of the Father the promise of the Holy Ghost, he hath shed forth this, which ye now see and hear. For David is not ascended into the heavens: but he saith himself, The Lord said unto my Lord, Sit thou on my right hand, until I make thy foes thy footstool. [Acts 2: 35, KJV 1769.]
>
> Therefore let all the house of Israel know assuredly, that God hath made that same Jesus, whom ye have crucified, **both Lord and Christ**. [Acts 2:36, KJV 1769.]

Born of the virgin Mary, the child in Bethlehem was named as the angel Gabriel had prescribed : Jesus. This name is a Greek transliteration of the name 'Joshua' which name, in turn, is fashioned from 'Jehovah' and the Hebrew word *yeshua*, meaning 'salvation'.

> And she shall bring forth a son, and thou shalt call his name JESUS: for he shall save his people from their sins. [Matthew 1:21, KJV 1769.]

The angel Gabriel so names Jesus, for 'he shall save his people from their sins'. And having done so, through suffering, death, bloodshed and resurrection, he was received up into heaven.

Ascended into heaven, as Peter declares in Acts, this same Jesus was made (and thence named) both Lord and Christ.

---

And it was given to the Apostle Paul, formerly Saul of Tarsus, a Pharisee, to first declare, publicly in preaching (see Acts 9:20) that the Lord Jesus Christ is the Son of God :

> And straightway he preached Christ in the synagogues, that he is **the Son of God**. [Acts 9:20, KJV 1769.]

Privately, some had testified that Jesus is the Son of God, such as Nathaniel (John 1:49) and Peter (Matthew 16:16) and the Ethiopian eunuch (Acts 8:37), but it is Paul, the Apostle, who first, in scripture, makes such a public declaration, in public preaching, and names Jesus Christ as the Son of God.

Therefore, in his exaltation, Jesus is given a name - that is to say he is identified and titled - above every other name.

> Wherefore God also hath highly exalted him, and **given him a name** which is above every name:That at the name of Jesus every knee should bow, of things in heaven, and things in earth, and things under the earth and that every tongue should confess that Jesus Christ is Lord, to the glory of God the Father.  [Philippians 2:9,10 KJV 1769.]

Those who name him appropriately, by the name Jesus and by the titles 'Lord' and 'Christ' and 'Son of God', bow the knee to him in so naming him.

Eventually, every knee shall bow to him . . . . to the glory of God the Father.

Comment: So what you are saying is that the name is the son of God?

Comment: @FaithMendel Firstly, Jesus has been identified as 'Lord and Christ'. Secondly, he has been identified as 'Son of God'. To name him appropriately, is to acknowledge whom he is : Lord Jesus Christ, the Son of God.

Comment: Still dosent answer the question definitely

Answer (score 3):

According to Vine’s Expository Dictionary of New Testament Words, the Greek word translated “name” can refer to “all that a name implies, of authority, character, rank, majesty, power, [and] excellence.”

After Jesus  completed his earthly sojourn he was exalted to the most highly favored position at his fathers right hand and given all authority in heaven and on earth.

This is seen in reading  Phillipians 2:9-10

> For this very reason, God exalted him to a superior position and kindly gave him the name that is above every other name,so that in the name of Jesus every knee should bend—of those in heaven and those on earth and those under the ground  and every tongue should openly acknowledge that Jesus Christ is Lord to the glory of God the Father.

This scripture shows that “the name” Jesus received refers to the position of authority he was given by God. The actual name is still Jesus but his name now stands for so much more.

[Insight on the scriptures](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200003177) says

> Because of remaining faithful to the very death, Jesus Christ was rewarded by his Father, receiving a superior position and “the name that is above every other name.” (Php 2:5-11) All those desiring life must recognize what that name stands for (Ac 4:12), including Jesus’ position as Judge (Joh 5:22), King (Re 19:16), High Priest (Heb 6:20), Ransomer (Mt 20:28), and Chief Agent of salvation. —Heb 2:10;
>
> Christ Jesus as “King of kings and Lord of lords” also is to lead the heavenly armies to wage war in righteousness. As executioner of God’s vengeance, he would be displaying powers and qualities completely unknown to those fighting against him. Appropriately, therefore, “he has a name written that no one knows but he himself.” —Re 19:11-16.

Like would be the case when a citizen is elected president he still has the same name but it now has a much different meaning.
His name is now synonymous with his powerful position.

Comment: Is it "in " or "at" the name?  Of Jesus ...

Comment: Not sure what you are asking Phillipians  says in the name

Comment: 'Philippians 2:10

AKJV That at the name of Jesus every knee should bow, of things in heaven, and things in earth, and things under the earth;

ASV that in the name of Jesus every knee should bow, of things in heaven and things on earth and notethings under the earth,

BBE So that at the name of Jesus every knee may be bent, of those in heaven and those on earth and those in the underworld,

Comment: The reason for translating “in the name of “or “at the name of” would be a question for the biblical hermeneutics site. That subtlety would not change the answer to your question however.

Comment: Phil 2:9-11 does not have the Greek for 'other' in the text. Any translation saying Jesus has been given the name that is above every [other] name must have square brackets around it, to show this word has been edited in. There is an important theological reason for [other] not being in the biblical text, as shown in John 17:11-12 where Jesus twice states that he has been given the name of the Father. But if [other] was actually in Phil.2 that would negate Jesus' words as to having the name of the Father, implying that Jesus' name is beneath the name of the Father.

Comment: @Anne which translation would you prefer?

Comment: Go to any or all Greek manuscripts used for translating Phil. 2:9-11, Kris, and you will not find the word 'other' anywhere. This is not a matter of preferring any one translation or other - this is about the original language manuscripts used for translations (into any language). The word 'other' has been added by the editors in whatever translation it appears in. It requires square brackets to show it is an editors addition to the text. I would prefer square brackets  in the NWT.

Comment: Is your objection simply that the word other should be bracketed to indicate it is not in original Greek manuscript or are you of the opinion that the word [other] should never be added by any translation to this or [other] Greek scriptures where the word [pas] is all that originally appears?

Comment: @anne The word for "all" here is a form of PAS. This word does not necessarily mean absolutely every thing. It can used in a relative sense without the thought of total inclusion of all things. This is clearly stated in most Greek lexicons and grammars.

Comment: @anne You write, "in John 17:11-12 ... Jesus twice states that he has been given the name of the Father". Jesus prays for the disciples to be kept in their faith by the power and authority of God, summarized as God's "name". Surely Jesus is not suggesting that "been given the name of the Father" means something as George Bush Sr. giving his same name to his son George Bush Jr.

Answer (score 2):

The name that He is given of the Father is **Jesus Christ**.

> Be it known unto you all, and to all the people of Israel, that by the name of **Jesus Christ** of Nazareth, whom ye crucified, whom God raised from the dead, even by him doth this man stand here before you whole.
>
> This is the stone which was set at nought of you builders, which is become the head of the corner.
>
> Neither is there salvation in any other: for **there is none other name under heaven given among men, whereby we must be saved**.
>
> Acts 4:10-12

Answer (score 1):

Christ is not some sort of "second name", but, however much Christians may have gradually disregarded this, a title, the Greek translation of the Hebrew word *maschiah* (from which Messiah) that means "anointed", implied king. As for Jesus, it is the English adaptation of the Hebrew name *Yeshua*, short for *Yehoshua*, which means “Yahweh saves”. That it was God who chose this name for His Son is confirmed by the words of the angel spoken to Joseph in a dream: "you will name him Jesus, because he will save his people from their sins" (Matt 1:21, see also Luke 1:31).

Jesus is made king by YHWH, and in his name there is salvatio in the name of his Father.

Comment: The way I read "Jesus is the Christ" is the all-important testimony that The Anointed One is the Savior of the world. He is the great Jehovah. The Hebrew word combined with a Greek one is a testament that He is the salvation of the world to both Jew and Gentile, to all of the children in the whole Earth, and that He is the God of the Old Testament as well as the God of the New, unchangeable from eternity to all eternity.

Answer (score -1):

Jesus Name, Jehovah is Salvation.

That's the name of Jesus, to point to God the Father at all time. Jehovah is Salvation.

YLT Luk 24:31: "31 and their eyes were opened, and they recognized him, and he became unseen by them."

Always not self but Jehovah, even His is God's Son.

YLT Gen 5:24: "24 And Enoch walketh habitually with God, and he is not, for God hath taken him."

Enoch (which means dedicated), no record of him except walketh habitually with God.  God manifested not self, and God hath taken him.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts on this question. However, this site is about documented beliefs of christian groups. You might improve your answer if you point us to the perspective your answer comes from and cite some (preferably authoritative) sources - especially concerning "Jehovah is Salvation" which you state several times.